# Do shocks to regime dependent impulse responses eventually return to 0 for a MS-VAR?

Tags: markov-process, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model, impulse-response

In VARs, the impulse response function reverts to 0. This indicates that the effect of the shock dies out. I have seen in VECMs (vector error correction models) that the impulse response functions (IRFs) do not always revert to 0. The justification for this is the VECM was non-stationary at level. 
However, will a regime dependent impulse response function revert to 0 in a Markov Switching VAR?